# iOS: Animating Incorrect Orientation at rootViewController?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, animation, orientation

Context: I am trying to perform a custom animation from a normal `UIViewController.view` to a `UISplitViewController.view`. The animation should show from Left to Right.

I set `self.window.rootViewController = viewController` where `viewController` is a normal `UIViewController`.

Once the user swipe, the following gets called:

```
UIView *theWindow = [viewController.view superview];

[viewController.view removeFromSuperview];
[theWindow addSubview:self.splitViewController.view];


CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setDuration:0.5];
[animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
[animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];

[[theWindow layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SwitchToView1"];
```

When the device is in a portrait mode, everything went perfectly. However, when the device is in the landscape mode, the transition animation performs as if the device is still in the portrait mode. For example: Instead of coming in from the left, it comes in from the bottom. The orientation of both the views are completely correct. Only the transition is weird.

Comment: If you rotate to landscape in the other direction, does the animation occur from the top? Or is it from the bottom regardless of which way you go into landscape mode? The constant brings the animation in from the left side of the layer. I wonder if the frame of the layer isn't updated, so what was the layer's left side is now on the bottom after rotation.

Comment: That is correct. The animation ignores any orientation changes. Any suggestion on how to make sure the layer gets updated?

Comment: I have the same problem - the orientation of the CALayer just doesn't seem to match up with its view. There seem to be a few other similar posts about it, but none of the solutions seem to work for me. Rotating the layer by 90 degrees of course also rotates the view, so that doesn't help..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, I've been playing around with your code (I did a best-guess reconstruction of how you have your project set up), and I was able to get the desired effect with the following code. I tried setting the frames and bounds of layers, of views, or sublayers, etc., and none of that worked. CATransform3D's, CATransform3DRotates, etc also weren't doing the trick. I also Googled for a solid hour. Either no one has had your issue, or no one has solved your issue. Regardless, this solution works, and unless some Core Animation guru can provide a better solution, you're welcome to this:

```
- (void)swipeGesture:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender {

UIView *theWindow = [self.viewController.view superview];

UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = self.viewController.interfaceOrientation;
NSString *subtypeDirection;
if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
    subtypeDirection = kCATransitionFromTop;
}
else if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
    subtypeDirection = kCATransitionFromBottom;
}
else {
    subtypeDirection = kCATransitionFromLeft;
}

[self.viewController.view removeFromSuperview];
[theWindow addSubview:self.splitViewController.view];

CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setDuration:0.5];
[animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
[animation setSubtype:subtypeDirection];
[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];

[[theWindow layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SwitchToView1"];
}
```

Comment: This solution works, although I am hoping for it not to come to this (manually adjust transition). I have other animation that depends on the window orientation that does not apply to this. Unless a better solution come along, I will mark your answer correct before the bounty is over. Thank you.

Comment: Understood. I am sorry I couldn't provide you with a better solution. I set up a sample project and spent a good 3 hours on this yesterday trying to find something. The idea is simple: Update the frame of the window's layer so that it matches up with the orientation of the initial view's layer. Sadly, putting that into practice doesn't seem as simple.

Comment: Am i right in thinking this only selects the correct direction for the transition? It still doesn't adjust the transition's "frame" size?